# Rounding up or down with decimals in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, decimal, excel-2007, digits

I need help rounding up with decimals in excel.

I need a formula that can help me round to a specific decimal. For example, I have a list of numbers with decimals, and I want that list to finish in either 9 or 5, see examples:

3.82 --> 3.85

5.38  --> 5.39

2.96  --> 2.95

9.45  --> 9.45 (remains the same)

9.06  --> 9.05

11.48  --> 11.49

6.12  --> 6.15

5.32  --> 5.35

If you see, I have values that end on .06, .38, .12 but I want them to finish on the nearest 9 or 5

Already tried roundup formulas but didnt work

Comment: Do you always round on 2 digits?

Comment: So what is the logic that 5.32 would be 5.35 instead of 5.29? It would both be offset by 0.03.

Comment: I for a pricing, so we would like to upper the price instead of loosing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
=(MROUND(A1*1000+5,50)-IF(MOD(MROUND(A1*1000+5,50),100)=0,10))/1000
```

- Multiplying by `1000` allows us to work with integers which gets away from the rounding issues that can occur when working with decimals. *This assumes your values have only two decimals. If there are more, a minor adjustment might be required.*  (eg, change `A1*1000+5` to `ROUND(A1*1000,0)+5`
- Add `5` since your rounding algorithm is offset from the actual mid-point
- Rounding to the nearest `50`

  - If the nearest `50` is a multiple of `100`, then subtract `10`
- Divide by `1000` to return the original value rounded per your algorithm

[image]

Comment: That's very neat!!

Answer (score 0):

That was a fun Puzzle:

```
=IF(ABS(A1-(ROUND(A1,1)-0.01))=ABS(A1-IF(ABS(A1-(ROUND(A1,1)+0.05))<ABS(A1-(ROUND(A1,1)-0.05)),ROUND(A1,1)+0.05,ROUND(A1,1)-0.05)),MAX(A1-(ROUND(A1,1)-0.01),IF(ABS(A1-(ROUND(A1,1)+0.05))<ABS(A1-(ROUND(A1,1)-0.05)),ROUND(A1,1)+0.05,ROUND(A1,1)-0.05)),IF(ABS(A1-(ROUND(A1,1)-0.01))<ABS(A1-IF(ABS(A1-(ROUND(A1,1)+0.05))<ABS(A1-(ROUND(A1,1)-0.05)),ROUND(A1,1)+0.05,ROUND(A1,1)-0.05)),ROUND(A1,1)-0.01,IF(ABS(A1-(ROUND(A1,1)+0.05))<ABS(A1-(ROUND(A1,1)-0.05)),ROUND(A1,1)+0.05,ROUND(A1,1)-0.05)))
```

Large puzzle as we need to find the two possibilities and test them to see which is closer and in the event of a tie return the max.

[image]